# ERROR Element type "jxb:bindings" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

Hey guys I am trying to create an external binding file that will help with clashing of property names. The errors I am getting are below.

[ERROR] Property "Rows" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

[ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

The external binding file looks like this.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jaxb:bindings>
                    <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
                            <jaxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
                    </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
                    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='title']">
                            <jaxb:property name="Atitle"/>
                    </jaxb:bindings>
            </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

I tried using this file and I get the error ERROR] Element type "jxb:bindings" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".Anyone have a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the error message is trying to tell you you have a jxb:bindings element with an unclosed attribute value or an unclosed start- or sole-tag.  I don't see it in your sample data, but then your sample data also doesn't use the namespace prefix given in the error message, so I expect something got changed en route.